# Excel sheet Column does not contain time in Date column But still showing times in DataGridView using c#

Tags: c#, excel, date, format, formatting

I am importing excel sheet in to DataGridView. My excel sheet contain one of the columns as a Date and this value is 12-05-2014. after importing into DataGridView it is showing 12-05-2014 00:00:00.

Let me how can i show only date not timings in DataGridView in windows applications

Answer (score 0):

DateTime always contains both Date and Time parts. You can remove time portion in following manner.

set the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` string to `"d"` in datagridview for that column.

or use ToShortDateString in aspx

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Upload Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# ((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileDate")).ToShortDateString() %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy";
```

or

You can set the format you want:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
this.date.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle;
// date being a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

you should be be mentioned your cell formatting only after databinding.

Comment: Still it is showing 12-05-2014 00:00:00 after setting DefaultCellStyle.Format string to "d".

Comment: you should be be mentioned your cell formatting only after databinding.

Comment: Sorry for my reply...i did after databinding. but it is showing time stamp also. Let me know is there any way to do ...